Flutter call recording not working for incoming calls, no file saved
I am developing a Flutter application to record voice calls (both incoming and outgoing) using the phone_state and record packages. The recording should save the conversation as a 3gp file, but when a call is received, it doesn’t record anything and no file is saved. Here’s the code I’m using:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:phone_state/phone_state.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class RecordCall extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordCall({super.key});
  @override
  State<RecordCall> createState() => _RecordCallState();
}

class _RecordCallState extends State<RecordCall> {
  bool granted = false;
  bool isRecording = false;
  late final AudioRecorder _audioRecorder;
  String? _audioPath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    try {
      _audioRecorder = AudioRecorder();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error initializing AudioRecorder: $e');
    }

    super.initState();

    PhoneState.stream.listen((PhoneState state) {
      debugPrint('Phone state: ${state.status}');
      if (state.status == PhoneStateStatus.CALL_STARTED) {
        if (!isRecording) {
          debugPrint('Starting recording...');
          startRecording();
        }
      } else if (state.status == PhoneStateStatus.CALL_ENDED) {
        if (isRecording) {
          debugPrint('Stopping recording...');
          stopRecording();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    try {
      final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      if (directory == null) {
        debugPrint('Directory is null');
        return;
      }

      final musicDirectory = Directory('${directory.path}/Music');
      if (!musicDirectory.existsSync()) {
        musicDirectory.createSync(recursive: true);
      }

      String filePath = '${musicDirectory.path}/${_generateTimestamp()}.3gp';

      await _audioRecorder.start(
        const RecordConfig(encoder: AudioEncoder.amrNb),
        path: filePath,
      );

    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('ERROR WHILE RECORDING: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopRecording() async {
    try {
      final path = await _audioRecorder.stop();
      if (path != null) {
        setState(() {
          isRecording = false;
          _audioPath = path;
        });
        debugPrint('Recording stopped: $_audioPath');
      } else {
        debugPrint('Recording stopped, but no file was created.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error while stopping recording: $e');
    }
  }

  String _generateTimestamp() {
    return DateFormat('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').format(DateTime.now());
  }
}

When an incoming call is received or placed (CALL_STARTED), the app should start recording the call, and save the file with a timestamped name (.3gp).
When the call ends (CALL_ENDED), the recording should stop, and the file should be saved.
I am using the phone_state package to detect incoming and outgoing calls.
The record package is used to handle the audio recording, and I’m saving the file to the external storage.
Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml is set as required:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Application when installed and started requests all permissions:
import 'package:voicenote/core/request_permission.dart';

Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  bool permissionsGranted = await PermissionHandler.requestPermissions();
  if (!permissionsGranted) {
    return;
  }

  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: SupabaseConfig.supabaseUrl,
    anonKey: SupabaseConfig.supabaseApiKey,
  );
  ForegroundTaskService.init();
  runApp(const VoiceNote());
}

request_permission.dart
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class PermissionHandler {
  static Future<bool> requestPermissions() async {
    var microphoneStatus = await Permission.microphone.request();
    var phoneStatus = await Permission.phone.request();
    var storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
    return microphoneStatus.isGranted && phoneStatus.isGranted && storageStatus.isGranted;
  }
}

